# How can I use Google Sheets API as database?

Tags: javascript, html, database, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to write a web application in javascript that reads and writes to a single Google sheet as a database. It basically reads from the sheet, make sure everything is in order, then writes to the sheet. All users will be using the same sheet, however I don't want the sheet to be able to be accessed outside the web application except for trusted users. I have a problem with writing to the sheet, as apparently it has to do O_Auth2 which has such poor documentation(where the hell do I put the key in the PUT request????) and all users would have to sign into my account. I don't think this would really work. Any ideas????

Thanks so much.

Comment: Why don't you use an SQL database?

Comment: I wouldn't use Google Sheets this way, but to each his/her own.  I would look at MySql, Postgres, Cassandra or CouchDB.  I think you're going to have more problems than you realize. There's a long blog post on the subject if you really want to do it this way: http://edba.xyz/google-sheets-as-database/